# SQL query to find record by value in multiple columns

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a sql table with multiple columns like

```
column1, column2, column3, column4, column5, column6,......, column400
```

And I need a SQL query to find a record that match the value from column3 to column400.

For ex:

```
select * 
from table 
where name in (column3,column4,column5, -----, column400).
```

As there are more than 400 columns in my table So I need a dynamic way that can compare any specific value to those columns.

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
from table t1, table t2 
where t1.column8 = t2.column3 
  and t1.primary_key = t2.primary_key
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: it will not help..............the columns in where condition are dynamic and too may,more than 400. So we can't define in where clause. We need a dynamic way.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way is

```
Select * 
from table 
where column1 = "name" && column2 = "name" ....... and column8 = "name"
```

Based on your requirement you can use AND OR,

Comment: #Manjunath, it's not feasible to put columns names in where conditions because there are too many columns (more than 400) to compare. So I need any dynamic way to compare one value with multiple columns.